# Bash scripting in Obsidian: Script to rename file and move it depending on frontmatter variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using the [Shell Commands plugin for Obsidian](https://github.com/Taitava/obsidian-shellcommands/) to do a number of things, e.g. run `latexmk` to convert a markdown file to PDF via LaTeX in order to render citations.

Now I'm trying to create a command that moves a file in a vault (a folder that Obsidian has open, pretty much like in VScode) to another location in the same vault depending on frontmatter variables. E.g. if it has `Medium: Book` it moves it too `Book Log`, and if it has `Medium: Movie` it moves it somewhere else.

My problem is a) that I'm not sure my syntax is correct, and b) that between the fact that I need to use plugin specific variables (e.g. `{{file_name}}`) and that the plugin can only deal with one-liners, I'm not sure where the problem is.

As a one-liner when I put it into the plugin it looks like this:

```
case {{file_name}} in 2*) : ;; *) mv {{file_path:absolute}} {{folder_path:absolute}}/{{date:YYYY-MM-DD}}\ {{file_name}} ;; esac; case {{yaml_value:Medium}} in Book | Audiobook | Podcast | eBook | GraphicNovel) mv {{file_path:absolute}}  {{vault_path}}/Book\ Log/{{date:YYYY}}/{{date:MM}}/{{file_name}} ;; Movie | TV | Game) mv {{file_path:absolute}}  {{vault_path}}/Movies\ and\ Games/{{date:YYYY}}/{{date:MM}}/{{file_name}};; esac
```

with line-breaks it looks like this:

```
case {{file_name}} in 
    2*) : ;; 
    *) mv {{file_path:absolute}} {{folder_path:absolute}}/{{date:YYYY-MM-DD}}\ {{file_name}} ;;  
esac; 

case {{yaml_value:Medium}} in 
Book | Audiobook | Podcast | eBook | GraphicNovel) mv {{file_path:absolute}} {{vault_path}}/Book\ Log/{{date:YYYY}}/{{date:MM}}/{{file_name}} ;; 
Movie | TV | Game) mv {{file_path:absolute}}  {{vault_path}}/Movies\ and\ Games/{{date:YYYY}}/{{date:MM}}/{{file_name}};; 

esac; exit; 

exec bash
```

This script is meant to do two things: rename the file with the current date IFF it doesn't already have a date prefixed to it, and move it to its correct location.
In the current above version it does either but not both upon a single execution. I.e. if the file starts with anything but a `2*` it prefixes the date. If and only if it already has a date (either from manually putting it there or a first execution of this command) it then moves that file to its correct location. I'd like this to happen in a single step.

My suspicion is that somehow the `mv` step after the first `esac` is being parsed as part of the second case but I can't figure out how to prevent that.

Any advice appreciated!
Thanks :)

Edit: I've taken steeldiver's advice and tried rewriting this directly in bash, but I'm still having trouble:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName=$1
f10="${fileName:0:10}"
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
year=$(date +"%Y")
month=$(date +"%m")

if [[ $f10 != [0-9]* ]] ; then 

    if grep -E '(Book|Audiobook|Podcast|eBook|GraphicNovel)' $1 ; then

        mv $1 "/home/Documents/Obsidian/Books and Movies/Book Log/$year/$month/$today $1"

    elif grep -E '(Movie|TV|Game)' $1 ; then
        
        mv $1 "/home/Documents/Obsidian/Books and Movies/Movies and Games/$year/$month/$today $1"

    fi

elif [[ $f10 = [0-9]* ]] ; then
    
     if grep -E '(Book|Audiobook|Podcast|eBook|GraphicNovel)' $1 ; then

        mv $1 "/home/Documents/Obsidian/Books and Movies/Book Log/$year/$month/$1"

    elif grep -E '(Movie|TV|Game)' $1 ; then
        
        mv $1 "/home/Documents/Obsidian/Books and Movies/Movies and Games/$year/$month/$1"

    fi
fi
```

Besides being a little inelegant because of the nested `if`s (I can't figure out how to use `case` here, I'm getting this error:

```
bash 2.sh "2023-09-05 aaa.md" 
grep: 2023-09-05: No such file or directory
grep: aaa.md: No such file or directory
grep: 2023-09-05: No such file or directory
grep: aaa.md: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The pragmatic solution might be to move the shell functionality to a script, and simply call **that**, with the Obsidian `{{file_name}}` etc. passed as positional parameters

Comment: My bash-fu is improving, but I'm still new at it, so could you maybe point me towards a tutorial or something like that which would explain this? Thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver I've added my attempt. Do you have any advice how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: ... I really just meant to place your existing case-based code in a script using positional parameters `"$1"`, `"$2"`, `"$3"` etc., and then execute that from Obsidian as `/path/to/myscript "{{file_name}}" "{{file_path:absolute}}" "{{folder_path:absolute}}" "{{yaml_value:Medium}}" "{{vault_path}}"`